# How to add google recaptcha in create react app?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, recaptcha, create-react-app

I'm trying to get the recaptcha response so that I can pass along it via `redux-form`.
Have tried the 2 methods below...

**Attempt 1**:
Specifying callback in `<head>`.

**index.html**:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=callback&render=explicit'></script>
```

The problem here is that the callback is in global scope but I need to access it in React components.

**Attempt 2**:
Specifying callback in DOM.

**Component**: handleRecaptcha(resp)

```
handleRecaptcha(resp) {
  console.log(resp);
}
```

**Component**: render():

```
<div className="g-recaptcha" data-callback={this.handleRecaptcha.bind(this)}  data-sitekey="***"></div>
```

**index.html**:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

I get the message `ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: function () { [native code] }` after submitting the recaptcha. Probably a scope problem too.

I'm trying to avoid using another library, since I think this is a rather trivial problem.
Would anyone happen to have any idea how to go about it?

All I need is to get hold of the `widget` instance, and do `grecaptcha.getResponse(widget)` to get the response. [API ref](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api)

Answer (score 3):

Use [react-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-recaptcha)

```js
import Recaptcha from 'react-recaptcha'

<Recaptcha
  sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  render="explicit"
  verifyCallback={verifyCallback}
  onloadCallback={callback}
/>
```

Comment: Ya this one also can be an alternative. I use it now

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Reaptcha](https://github.com/sarneeh/reaptcha).

It is a lot cleaner, more modern and has more of a React-way approach in handling the reCAPTCHA widget.

```
<Reaptcha 
  sitekey="YOUR_API_KEY" 
  onVerify={() => {
    // Do something
  }}
/>
```